# Cant apply map function inside map function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problems when i try to apply map function into html on react.. Here is my code:

```
response = [
  data : {
    name: 'john',
    title: 'john doe',
    images: {
      slider: {
        desktop: 'link1',
        mobile: 'link2'
      },
      carrousel: {
        desktop: 'link1',
        mobile: 'link2'
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    name: 'Mary',
    title: 'Mary doe',
    images: {
      slider: {
        desktop: 'link1',
        mobile: 'link2'
      },
      carrousel: {
        desktop: 'link1',
        mobile: 'link2'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Then i apply lodash to pick the info:

```
 const all = _
      .chain(response)
      .filter(item => item)
      .flatMap(data => data)
      .map(item => _.pick(item, ['name', 'title','images']))
      .value()
```

And now i apply on the html:

```
return (
    all.map((element, index) => (
     <div className='content' key={index}>
        <h1>{element.name}</h1>
        <h2>{element.title}</h1>
      {
        _.filter(element => element.images_group != 
        undefined).map(image => image.slider).map(element => (
          <img alt='' src={element.desktop} key={index} />
        ))
       }
     </div>
     ))
  })
```

it does not return an error, simply does not show any image.. it does not appear in the HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: your filter and map function are returning the exact same result (they are not changing your array). Check underscore docs

Comment: Okey, thanks, any way i have to map the image field, right? for access to image.slider

Comment: What is the purpose of the `flatMap` part? That only makes sense for nested arrays.

Comment: The original response is nested array, and all the info is inside 'data'

Comment: I don't see any nested array. I see an array with objects inside, not an array with arrays inside.

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure its because you haven’t wrapped your map in brackets. All javascript variables, functions, etc after the return need to be in brackets.

Comment: They have brackets, I forgot put them in the example, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not clear on the structure of your response.
 If your response is an array of objects, then you need to get rid of the `data` key.

```
response = [
 {
   name: 'john',
   title: 'john doe',
   images: {
    slider: {
     desktop: 'link1',
     mobile: 'link2'
    },
    carrousel: {
     desktop: 'link1',
     mobile: 'link2'
    }
 }
},
 {
  name: 'Mary',
  title: 'Mary doe',
  images: {
   slider: {
    desktop: 'link1',
    mobile: 'link2'
  },
   carrousel: {
     desktop: 'link1',
     mobile: 'link2'
   }
  }
 }
]
```

You just need to assign the `jsx` output from lodash to a variable and then render the output using curly bracket

```
renderData (){
   const all = _
  .chain(response)
  .filter(item => item)
  .flatMap(data => data)
  .map(item => _.pick(item, ['name', 'title','images']))
  .value();

    const allData 
      = all.map((element, index) => (
      <div className='content' key={index}>
           <h1>{element.name}</h1>
          <h2>{element.title}</h2>
      {
       _.filter(element => element.images_group 
          != undefined)
       .map(image => image.slider).map(element => (
         <img alt='' src={element.desktop} key={index} />
      ))
      }
      </div>
   ))
   return (
     <div>{allData}</div>
   )
}
```